# Error while transpiling Typescript files using Babel

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, babeljs, transpiler

I'm transpiling my typescript files using babel configured in `webpack.config.js` but somehow it is not working for me and I'm getting errors whenever I'm running `npm run watch` which says `SyntaxError: xxxxx: Unexpected token` for almost 13-14 files.

Below are my configuration files and error description. Could anyone please highlight the mistake or had faced the similar issue then please do mention.

Thanks!

> Error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\EndNode.ts: Unexpected token (4:11)

export class BlankEndNode extends Node {
public readonly isEndNode: boolean = true;
}
```

> Webpack file

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'development';

console.log('Webpack running in ' + mode + ' mode');

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: false
        }
    },
    devtool: ('development' === mode) ? 'inline-source-map' : 'none',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|js)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|otf|eot|png|svg|jpg)(\?.*$|$)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyPlugin({
           patterns: [
                { from: "./src/images/", to: "images/" }
            ]
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', ".css", ".scss"]
    }
};
```

> babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        { "modules": "commonjs" }
      ],
        "@babel/typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible repo? Before that you might need to double check that the configuration file again since you have had 2 `resolve` property in there

Comment: Sorry, don't mind, but the repo cannot be shareable. Also which configuration file you are mentioning here?

Comment: the `webpack.config.js` file has a duplicated `resolve` property you might need to merge them and re-run again

Comment: Ohh Ok let me do that first

Comment: Still no success

Comment: Hmmm. I think I can't help you until you create a small repo which includes the config and  simple entry point having your code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232020/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-vin).